# AngularJS: on-click if pristine OR if dirty and valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have an input field:

```
<input name="fName" type="text" class="form-control dude.firstName"
     ng-trim="false"
     ng-pattern="patterns.name"
     ng-model="dude.firstName"
     ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
     required>
<span class="error" ng-show="idForm.fName.$error.pattern">
     Please only use letters, forward slashes, and hyphens
</span>
```

My requirements are this:

1. If user has not changed anything, it needs to run saveIdentification
2. If user has changed something and it is not valid, then stop and allow the form to display the message
3. If the user has changed something and it is valid, then run saveIdentification

   ```
   <span 
       ng-show="localEditing.id=='SAVE'" 
       tabindex="0" 
       title="Save Changes" 
       class="globalIcon-save action-edit-button" 
       ng-click="(idForm.$pristine || (idForm.$dirty && idForm.$valid)) && saveIdentification()">
   </span>
   ```

The solution above fulfills requirements 1 and 2 but not 3.  It will not save if the form is changed and valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below snippet. I just made a slight variation to your code in order to receive the form object as a parameter in the `saveIdentification` function.

*Notice* that I added an input with `ng-maxlength="3"` in order to reproduce the scenario where the form is invalid (When the input text is larger than 3)

When the conditions described by you are met a "*ran saveIdentification!*" text is logged in the browser console (devtools).

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.wizard = {
      saveIdentification: fnSaveIdentification
    };

    return vm.wizard;

    function fnSaveIdentification(form) {debugger;
      if (form && (form.$pristine || form.$valid)) {    //<-- Condition here!
        console.log('ran saveIdentification!');
      }
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">

  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="i1" type="text" ng-maxlength="3" ng-model="ctrl.input">
    <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.saveIdentification(myForm)">Submit</a>

    <!-- Display message here!! (modify as you need it)-->
    <span ng-show="myForm.$invalid">Form is invalid</span>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ng-disabled="(idForm.$dirty && idForm.$invalid))"
ng-click="saveIdentification()"
>

<span ng-show="(idForm.$dirty && idForm.$invalid))">
Your error message goes here!!!
</span>
```

Comment: This fuilfills requirements 1 and 3 but not 2.  If the user has entered invalid data and clicks the save icon, it runs saveIdentification().

Comment: Same.  Please see above where I have included information about the validation being done.

Comment: Why are you using span instead of button for click?? If you use button then you can use ng-disabled as I suggested.

Comment: But, Why use `ng-disabled`? Is this a requirement or just an option introduced by you, @SamB? When the OP says "`... not valid, then **stop** and...`" I think it means, not to continue the execution of the function, but not to disable the ability to call the function.